# Converging zeroes of a $M$-smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

A function $f: \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is $M$-smooth, i.e.
$$|f(x+h)-f(x) -\langle \boldsymbol\nabla f(x), h \rangle| < M\|h\|^2  $$
Suppose, we have sequence of zeroes of $f$, given by $x_n$ converging to $x^*$, would $f$ be zero in a neighbourhood of $x^*$?

Comment: Is the inequality supposed to be true for all $x,h \in \mathbb R^p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be $f(y,z)=y$. Then $f$ is $M$-smooth for any $M>0$ since $|f(\vec{x}+\vec{h})- f(\vec{x})-\langle\nabla f(x), h \rangle|=0$. There is a sequence of zeroes converging to $x^*=(0,0)$ and yet $f$ is not zero in any neighborhood of $x^*$.